# Match values to table with limiting values in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, input

I have a dataframe where I would like to append values to if the id value is the same. I do not wish to have duplicate rows in my df1 dataframe

**Data**

df1

```
    id      stat        
    aa11rr  y       
    aa11rr  y       
    aa11rr  y       
    bb123   n       
    bb123   n
```

df2

```
loco    country temp    
aa11rr  ny      55  
aa11rr  ny      60  
aa11rr  ny      65  
bb123   ca      75  
bb123   ca      70  
aa11rr  ny      70  
bb123   ca      90  
bb123   ca      95
```

**Desired**

```
id      stat    loco    country temp    
aa11rr  y       aa11rr  ny      55  
aa11rr  y       aa11rr  ny      55  
aa11rr  y       aa11rr  ny      60  
bb123   n       bb123   ca      75  
bb123   n       bb123   ca      70
```

**Doing**

```
pd.concat([df1, df2.reindex(df1.index)], axis=1)
```

However, I would like my smaller dataset to not have more rows than it started with

Comment: I do not see how do you apply your rule. The `aa11rr` value in the `id` column is repeated three times in df2. Which one will you pick to go with the first row? the second row? or any other row in df1 where they have same `id` value?

Comment: will update this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC

```
extract = lambda x: pd.merge(x, df2, left_on='id', right_on='loco').head(len(x))
out = df1.groupby('id').apply(extract).reset_index(drop=True)
print(out)

# Output
       id stat    loco country  temp
0  aa11rr    y  aa11rr      ny    55
1  aa11rr    y  aa11rr      ny    60
2  aa11rr    y  aa11rr      ny    65
3   bb123    n   bb123      ca    75
4   bb123    n   bb123      ca    70
```

Comment: why do you need `groupby`?

Comment: It's easier to truncate the number of rows for each group :)

Comment: I see. Nice! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if your example reflects what you want to do. However, *getting all rows from `df2` to `df1` where they agree on `df1.id` and `df2.loco`* is called left outer join. You can do so by `pandas.DataFrame.merge()` method. Documentation is [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html). This should do the trick:

```
df1.merge(df2, left_on='id', right_on='loco', how='left')
```

Comment: thank you shouldnt df2 be within the parenthesis? @ahmed

Comment: yes, you are right. I fixed it.